# Getting the results of a query, depending on results of first query

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables. 1 named `tasks` that has the rows `[id, event_id, title]` and the other table is named `task_items` with the rows `[id, task_id, description, ...]`.

I am trying to run a query to retrieve all tasks with an `event_id` of x, then all task_items that match the `id` of any result from the previous query. I currently have 2 standalone queries, but don't know how to join them to work in-tandem. The current code that I have show all `task_items` associated with the event, but they aren't corresponding with each task. Task 0 in my database has 0 `task_items`, but my code is displaying the `task_items` for task 0 under task 1.

This is my query code:

```
$tasks = DB::table('tasks')->where('event_id', $request->route('id'))->get();
    foreach($tasks as $task)
    {
        $taskItemID[] = $task->id;
    }
    $taskItems = DB::table('task_items')->whereIn('task_id', $taskItemID)->get();
```

This is my foreach loop:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
                    <div><b>Task # {{$task->id}}:</b> {{$task->title}}</div>
                    <div style="float:right;">mark as completed</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #efefef;padding: 20px;">
                    @foreach($taskItems as $taskItem)
                      <li>{{$taskItem->description}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                      @endforeach
```

Comment: @KamleshPaul is there a way to do this without Laravel relationship? I don't want to create a model for this as it isn't something I'd use (except for this feature). If there is no alternative, then so be it.

Comment: It's 2 minutes' work to make the model, then your code becomes `$event->tasks()->with("items")->get();` or similar.

Comment: @sirhB hello ? are you there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to tweak @Kamlesh Paul's code a bit, but this worked for me:

```
$tasksData = DB::table('tasks')->where('event_id', $request->route('id'))->get();
    foreach ($tasksData as $task) {
          $temp = $task;
          $temp->task_items = DB::table('task_items')->where('task_id', $task->id)->get();
          $tasks[] = $temp;
    }
```

Comment: You must've edited it after I tried your code because it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

### As you don't want to use Model then

try somthing like this to create new child data

```php
$tasksData = DB::table('tasks')->where('event_id', $request->route('id'))->get();
    $tasks = collect();
    foreach ($tasksData as $task) {
          $temp = $task;
          $temp->task_items = DB::table('task_items')->where('task_id', $task->id)->get();
          $data[] = $temp;
    }
return $tasks;
```

then you can get `$tasks` with all the `$task_items` to get all `task_item` you can `$tasks[0]->task_items`

you can use in your blade like this

```php
@foreach($tasks as $task)
<div><b>Task # {{$task->id}}:</b> {{$task->title}}</div>
<div style="float:right;">mark as completed</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #efefef;padding: 20px;">
    @foreach($task->task_items as $taskItem)
    <li>{{$taskItem->description}}</li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

> **NOTE** i am not recommend  this but at in your can you can use this

Comment: The query is returning an empty array

Comment: So there was a small error with the query, which I fixed, but now I am getting an error saying `Undefined property: stdClass::$task_items`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pAGwvCpw This is the data I am getting. I would like to get an array of the 2 tasks with an inner-array if there are matching task_items.

Comment: @sirhB please check now